# Sum and group by in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection with fields `projectId` and `amount`. How can I return number of documents in this collection having `projectId = 7` and the sum of `amount` in documents in the collection also having `projectId = 7`?

It seems that MongoDB does support aggregation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) but I cannot find anything specific for Meteor.

Comment: Are the documents already published to the client or do you need the calculation on the server? Some context will help in providing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, you can use the **[meteorhacks:aggregate package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** to implement the aggregation:

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Then simply use **`.aggregate`** function like below.

```
var project = new Mongo.Collection('projects');
var pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": { "projectId": 7 }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$projectId",
                "total_amount": { "$sum": "$amount" }
            }
        }
];
var result = projects.aggregate(pipeline);
```